# what are single linked lists used for?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I know that arraylists and doublelinked lists are commonly used in programming. I know there are other different kinds of ways to make a list. Single linked lists Im told single linked lists are not commonly used in programming lists. I was wonder what can singlelinked lists be used for.

Comment: Reference linking uses single-linked lists in the traditional sense as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

It's a data structure, so generally, it's used to hold data. The main uses I've seen specifically for singly versions though are

- For learning to program. It's an extremely common assignment in schools to write one. They work basically the same as a doubly linked list, but are simpler to write. Knowledge of how a SLL works can transfer to when you try to write a DLL. They're also the simplest recursive structure (that I know of), so knowledge of them can transfer to more complex structures like recursive trees as well.
- Many functional languages make extensive use of SLLs since they work so well with recursive functions and immutability. Each recurse you detach the head, "modify it", then reattach the "modified head" to the result of recursing. This is how simple iteration is done in functional programming. A DLL wouldn't work here since the backwards reference each node holds would force you to update/make a copy of every reference in the every node every time you tried to detach/attach a head; which would lead to ridiculous time complexities.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you only need to iterate forwards
2. When you only need to add or remove elements at the front